Deploy container image to azure container App with environment variables
I've setup one pipeline in azure devops to build container image, push to ACR and deploy to container app with environment variables.
Below is script which i was trying, but unable to set environment variables.
trigger: none

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'dockerRegistryServiceConnection'
  imageRepository: 'imageRepository'
  containerRegistry: 'containerRegistry'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  group: DevAppSettings  

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy to Azure Container Apps
  jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: Deploy to Azure Container Apps
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'azureSubscription'
        scriptType: bash
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          envVars=""
          for var in $(printenv | cut -d'=' -f1); do
            value=${!var}
            envVars+=" $var='$value' "
          done
          az containerapp update \
            --name pomaster-api-dev \
            --resource-group POMaster-resource-group \
            --image pomasterdev.azurecr.io/pomaster:$(Build.BuildId) \
            --set-env-vars $envVars


I'm still unable to set environment variables.
What's wrong here? Please help!
I am expecting to deploy container image with all variables defined in variable group as environment variables.

I think you have to define the variables like: - name: name of the variable, next line with a tab so it lines up with the letter n of name and set value: with the value you want. That is the way I use to define variables. I don't know if your approach is different and won't work the way I mention.. learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/… see an example about what I mean. Sorry if you already knew this

The command az containerapp update in AzureCLI@2 can update container app environment variables on my side.

Your problem could be caused:

The envVars doesn't have correct value.

You are reading from agent enviroment printenv, there are many values, and the name could have specicial characters like (), which cannot be used to set as variable name.
If you run echo $envVars in AzureCLI@2 to check the value, it could report:


I am expecting to deploy container image with all variables defined in variable group as environment variables.

To deploy with variables in variable group, you can specify the variables $(var) in the command:
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Deploy to Azure Container Apps
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'ARMConn_ACR'
      scriptType: 'bash'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        envVars="envvar6='$(var6)' envvar7='$(var7)'"
        az containerapp update \
          --name wadecontainerapp \
          --resource-group testRG \
          --image mcr.microsoft.com/k8se/quickstart:latest \
          --set-env-vars $envVars

If you still would like to read from environment variable, filter the target variables and make sure the $envVars have correct value. Or you can use azure cli az pipelines variable-group list to get the variables and filter the value then. Please note it will not list secret type variable value.

In the AzureCLI@2 pipeline log, make sure the  "provisioningState" is "Succeeded" as shown in my first screenshot. If it's failed, you can firstly check the command locally for debugging.

